# How to access containers in EC2?

Tags: node.js, docker, amazon-ec2, docker-compose

I try to deploy a NodeJS (NestJS) application on Ec2 instance, so I create Ec2 instance and connect to them via ssh, install Git, Node, Docker, Docker-compose etc. When I run only `nest start` to run my node.js app then everything is fine and I see my app from the browser (but only when I set MyIP in inbound rules, why? - I've had also all Http/Https rules...).

But I can't do this in this way because I have to use docker-compose with two services - Api and Redis.

my docker-compose looks like here:

```
version: '3.7'

networks:
  proxy:
    name: proxy

services:
  redis:
    image: redis:6.2-alpine
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    command: ["redis-server", "--requirepass", "redisPass12345!"]
    networks: 
      - proxy

  worker:
    container_name: worker
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - redis
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    expose: 
      - '8080'
      - '3005'
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    command: npm run dev
    networks:
      - proxy
```

When I build and up docker-compose with:

```
sudo docker-compose up
```

and open browser then I see that `this site cannot be reached`... Can someone tell me what have i doing wrong?

here is also my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:16.3.0-alpine as builder

WORKDIR /dist

COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install --force

COPY . .
RUN  npm run build

EXPOSE 8080

CMD [ "npm", "run", "dev"]
```

and Inbound rules:
[image]

PS. One more thing, my `process.env.PORT` is set to `3005`.

Comment: Do you have the same issue running this setup locally, not on an EC2 instance?  You have many unnecessary options in your Compose file (`networks:`, `container_name:`, `expose:`, `volumes:`, and the application `command:` can probably all be deleted); are any of these necessary to run the application, or can you delete them in the question?  (Is this a programming question, or just an AWS deployment question?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your application is listening on port 3005, you should expose this port also in your docker-compose.yaml, and also in the AWS inbound rules.

Try to `docker ps` to and see which port at exposed for your nodejs application.

Comment: I run `docker-compose` with `-d` flag, after `docker ps` ports  looks like here: ` 0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, :::8080->8080/tcp` for app

Comment: Exactly, but your process.env.PORT is 3005. try to expose this port also.

Comment: Ok, i set ` expose: 
      - '8080'
      - '3005'
` in docker-compose, but still I can't reach this container :/

Comment: Please post your new docker-compose.yaml in your post,

also, which domain are you trying to connect via chrome ?

Comment: If the application port is 3005, why is the container port is 8080 ?

ports:
      - 8080:8080
      - 3005:3005

Comment: Thank you, working now but only when I add port to url, what to do to use only dsn without port?

Comment: Great, What do you mean using dns without port ? you can use port 80 (default for http) or 443 (default for https), but in some cases it would't work because port 80 is already taken by another resource.

Comment: Right now, when i trigger in browser for `...compute.amazonaws.com/heartbeat` then this site can't be reached but when i add port 3005 and url looks like this h `...compute.amazonaws.com:3005/heartbeat` then everything is fine